# mdi-vue icons display twice

Tags: vue.js, icons, material-design

I am using the [Material Design Icons for Vue.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdi-vue) library and when I try to display an icon it is shown twice and can only be fixed by removing the `::before` which contains the smaller duplicate.

(I would usually put this code in a JSFiddle but the mdi-vue library cannot be used in there)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <PowerIcon />

  <div class='fixed'>
    <PowerIcon />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
import PowerIcon from 'mdi-vue/Power'

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    PowerIcon
  }
})
```

CSS

```
.fixed .mdi-power::before {
  display: none;
}
```

Results in:

[image: mdi-vue-bug]

Am I using the library incorrectly or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error might appear, when using two different approaches in parallel to include the Material Design Icon Library.

Check if your `index.html` links to a css file that handles material design icons. Something like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">`

This happens for example when you installed [Vuetify over Vue CLI](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/) or when you were testing other options to use Material Design Icons.

Comment: I did have Vuetify installed before and it appears I have butchered its uninstall. It would be nice if Vuetify had uninstall documentation  :/

Answer (score 0):

From my investigation like [Uchendu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554968/4424898) had answered it was the CSS affecting the icons. I saw that the ::before had the icon as content apart from the SVG. I made a global CSS rule

```
*[class*="mdi-"]::before {
  content: none;
}
```

This reversed the material design CSS and only one icon now displays